Issue with Character Encoding for ASCII symbols for API request in SpringBoot application
I am working on a Spring Boot application that uses OpenAPI for generating APIs. One of the endpoints, sendEmail, accepts a request body containing toAddress, subject, emailBodyAsHtml, and attachments. The structure is as follows:
yaml file sample
bodyHtml:
  type: String
attachments:
  type: array
  items:
    format: binary
    type: String
 encoding:
   attachments:
     contentType: application/pdf
   bodyHtml:
     contentType: text/html;charset=UTF-8


Sample request:
<html><body><p>Price is 100€</p></body></html>

Inside the controller, I am recieving as
<html><body><p>Price is 100??</p></body></html>

If I remove attachment(as it is optional) in the request encoding is working as expected.
I have deployed the project on AWS
Could someone please guide me on how to resolve this encoding issue?
If I remove attachment(as it is optional) in the request encoding is working as expected.

Based on my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48952844/986160 you could run:
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"

or based on answer How to set UTF-8 character encoding in Spring boot?
you cound add config file (for application /var/app/app.jar it will be /var/app/app.conf) below line:
export LANG='en_US.UTF-8'

